# How to maximize comprehension if worldbuilding is complicated?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

Parts of my worldbuilding are critical to the plot. Not understanding the world means not understanding stakes and the failure conditions.

I need to make clear some parts of the world to show what's at stake. The problem is that some people seem to miss the explanation, which is split into bits and woven in and around dialogue. I dramatized these worldbuilding points, and then actually summarized them in the protag's internal dialog 'oh, I see, so if I fail x I'm dead'. Flew right past them.

***First example***
The Federation is a monopolistic oligarchy. If you have 1 groundbreaking innovation, you get it assessed. If assessment is positive, you earn a monopoly (e.g. if you make steam engines, no one is allowed to make steam engines with those parameters), and can ask for Corporate Family status (this status grants Family members legal immunity). If you have 2 such monopolies and over 10 billion market capitalization value, you can ask to join the Council of Primes (a CF leader is called Prime) that rules the Federation. In terms of decision making, it's like monarchy but with a council of variable size instead of 1 person.
Much like you can gain CF status, you lose it if you can't guarantee your product (2 strikes and you're out) or if you go bankrupt.
My protag is CF and takes a gamble. If they win, they become Prime, if they lose, they lose CF status, lose their legal immunity, and probably everyone will send assassins after them.

***Second example***
In order to practice the magic, you have to become a sociopath. You take a course for it (it's a horrible course). This also generates the inability to grok human facial expressions. I explained this in dialogue to a trainee by illustrating sociopathic behavior (callousness, promiscuity) and then summarized into one sentence in internal dialogue at the end of explanation 'this means sociopathy' (used the actual word). The readers picked up on the inability to recognize expressions but took the sociopathy as a minor inconvenience.

How would you go about presenting/dramatizing this type of information to make sure readers get it and its exact magnitude?

Did you ever experience a similar situation with reader comprehension before?

Are my problems because the worldbuilding is simply too complicated? It doesn't feel like rocket science to me.

Comment: "It doesn't feel like rocket science to me." Well, you are the story's author, so all of the plot lines and worldbuilding are there in your brain.

Comment: maybe the reader was a sociopath so they didn't see it as a problem, tbh the first example is a little complicated but it was described in a condensed way

Comment: So I also worry about this, and I've come up with two solutions: 1 have a seperate encyclopedia of your own world. Similar to the appendix in some novels (eragon, circe) this allows for dry descriptions that explain anything the reader might not be able to understand from the context of the chapter. 2 Be a better writer.  I'm not being funny or mean, be better at enticing the reader into learning.  Weave the worldbuilding into the narrative.  Any interaction between characters can lenditself to this.  There's also narrative exposition, andre norton does this well in sargasso space. Good Luck

Comment: Your readers may be as dumb as bricks. If so, there's no cure for that; other than finding readers with more accurate sensibilities. usually with worldbuilding you should only show of it as much as is necessary for the story to move forward. Add action to any explanation. Hang life & death situations on the explication. Widen your circle of readers & see if they're smarter.

Comment: This is really a writing question. Here in Worldbuilding, we're here to help you build your world. You've apparently got that already! I'd suggest asking over on the writing stack. The long and short of it boils down to you are going to, if you don't already know, learn & practice the art of writing. That's something that is well outside our charter!

Comment: Agree with elemtias's point. What you're asking is how to convey information to the reader, which is a problem that the Writing.SE is better equipped to deal then we are. You're better off asking for their help.

Comment: Story telling and worldbuilding are different things. I know what iron man does. He has a cool suit. I don't need to know how his suit is made of nanomachines assembled at a subatomic level, powered by a semi-magic nuclear reactor that will slowly poison him to death unless he discovers a new element in his basement; to know what he can do in the suit.

Answer (score 3):

**Always explain the WHY**

Firstly, I suspect that this could just as easily be asked over on the writing.se site as this is a problem that a lot of writers have when they put forward rules that are not commonly known, whether for a built world or not. The real issue here is that you have a complete model in your head and you can even feel the emotional impact of that model, but your readers just don't have that same model. Respectfully, you just demonstrated that in your two examples.

In the first, you finish with a line that says that assassins may be sent after you. But, nothing in the mechanics you described before that (the HOW) explained how these two are connected. I understand financial ruination and bankruptcy and how it might feel for someone who is rich (not that I have ever been either rich or bankrupt before, but I've seen the movie Wall St) but just because someone goes from being rich to being poor, it doesn't make others want to kill them and it's counter-intuitive;

1) That person's enemies will want him living in destitution for as long as possible to make him suffer

2) Some poor people may want to knock him down a couple of pegs now that he's among the plebiscite, but they won't be able to afford, let alone have a reason to, kill the man.

In the second example, you focus again on the HOW of developing sociopathy, but you don't explain WHY it is more than a minor inconvenience in your world. Again, it seems counter-intuitive given that a lot of sociopaths in OUR world seem to do quite nicely for themselves.

In my experience, the art of world-explaining (as opposed to world-building) is about taking those parts of your world that are *different* to ours, and explaining them and them alone. The rest of it your readers will fill in with what they already know. In other words, if you don't explain it, people just assume it's the same as this world.

In both the cases you provided, you told us the how of the construct, but then told us the effect and in both cases, if we fill in with what we know about how OUR world works, the impact you describe just isn't there. So, while you have some great world mechanics there both in terms of economic structure and magic, you've done enough to explain them. What you haven't done (and really needs doing) is explaining the sociological aspects of your world that lead to the great impacts that you describe.

Put more simply, now that you have a working economy and magic lore, now you have to explain how your people feel about it all so as to fill in that one missing piece of the puzzle. Without that, we will all assume that your society thinks and has similar values to us, and from where I'm standing that cannot be if the impacts on your protagonist are as bad as you say for failure.

Comment: This is an alternate earth, so values and social implications are equivalent. Losing social status is bad on its own. Partly losing the ability to maintain meaningful social connections and numbing of certain emotional aspects (as it happens in sociopathy) is also bad. These things are actually explained but I haven't said I explained them for the sake of question brevity.